# Get metadata about OpenML dataset

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, openml

I'm trying to get the metadata for an OpenML data specifically about the features. I have an image below from the website

[image]

I've been using SKLearn's fetch_openml, but it doesn't seem to contain all the proper data I need. I primarily need to be able to get the number of categorical and numeric features as well as their average unique value, which can be obtained via Pandas, but it might be harder to distinguish between nominal and numeric features as that's not always consistent with the data type of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that information in their [documentation](https://openml.github.io/openml-python/main/examples/30_extended/datasets_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-examples-30-extended-datasets-tutorial-py).

```py
import openml
import pandas as pd
from openml.datasets import edit_dataset, fork_dataset, get_dataset


openml_list = openml.datasets.list_datasets()  # returns a dict
datalist = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(openml_list, orient="index")
```